# How to Get area of visible map in Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps

I have set map view successfully in iPhone with current location with maximize zoom.

like,

```
myMapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

.....

```
span.latitudeDelta=0.0001;
span.longitudeDelta=0.0001;
```

...

Now i want to get complete area of visible portion of Map from its center point in any of measure like km,m,number etc.

any help..

Answer (score 0):

Its really easy to do that:

```
MKMapRect visibleRect = [myMapView visibleMapRect];
```

Then there are some functions to measure the rectangle in meters such as:

```
CLLocationDistance MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(
    MKMapPoint a,
    MKMapPoint b
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html) and [Sample Code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/WorldCities/Introduction/Intro.html)

And try something like this:

```
MKCoordinateRegion yourRegion;
// Take a look at Lisbon Downtown
yourRegion.center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(38.715, -9.140);
yourRegion.span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.02, 0.02);
[self.mapView setRegion:yourRegion animated:YES];
```